# Create a custom exception for a JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, exception, jspinner

I have two `JSpinner` components for which I've created a custom exception and it was working very well.
Yesterday I modify the spinner in Netbeans, I added a spinner model editor because I wanted only positive numbers.

So now I have only positive numbers but when I put something like -1 it does not display the error message like before, why?

Here's my code:

```
   public int getAlerte() {
        int res = 0;

        if (Integer.parseInt(jSpinnerTime.getValue().toString()) <= 0 ||
            Integer.parseInt(jSpinnerTime.getValue().toString()) >1000) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Time should be between 1 and 1000",
                    "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            res = 1;
        }       
        if (res == 0){
            int visperiod = Integer.parseInt(jSpinnerTime.getValue().toString())/2;            
            if (Integer.parseInt(jSpinnerFreqV.getValue().toString()) <= 0 ||
                Integer.parseInt(jSpinnerFreqV.getValue().toString()) > visperiod){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Visualization frequency should be between 1 and "+visperiod,
                    "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            res = 1;
            }

        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use an [`int` based `SpinnerNumberModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html#SpinnerNumberModel%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) with appropriate values for the 4 x `int`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: That's what is use in the SpinnerNumberModel. OK for the SSCCE will use it next  time, thank you

Comment: *"will use it next time"*  Will try to answer next time.  ..Though you might also edit *this* question to include an SSCCE.

Comment: I second the request for the SSCCE. I for one am not sure what it is  you're asking here.

Comment: So no one can help me, i tried without the visperiod and it's always not working, thx

Comment: *"So no one can help me,"*  I expect we can once an SSCCE is posted.   *"i tried"*  Try preparing an SSCCE.  If that very process does not make the problem evident, you will end with a short code that others can use to reproduce the problem.  As it is now, all we can do is guess.  I'm not good at guessing, and not willing to try on this occasion.

Comment: ok i go to learn now about the SSCCE and will get back here thank you

Comment: I really don't understand what is SSCCE but if fixed my problem i go to read the faq about the SSCCE, thank you very much for all

Answer (score 0):

i tried the SSCCE and i hope it usefull for you, here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class JPanelPoly extends LayerPanel{

    private RendererContainer rc = new RendererContainer();
    private ParametersTable parametersTable= new ParametersTable("TYPE");
    private int nbrParameter; 
    private int nbrCenter; 
    private Frame parent;


    public JPanelPolyg() {
    initComponents();
        jListParameter.setModel(rc.getModel());
    jListParameter.setCellRenderer(new SimpleRenderer());
    jSpinnerEnters.setValue(150);

    }

    public JPanelPoly(Frame parent,int nbrCenter, int nbrParameter){
    initComponents();
    this.nbrCenter = nbrCenter;
    this.nbrParameter = nbrParameter;
    jListParameter.setModel(rc.getModel());
    jListParameter.setCellRenderer(new SimpleRenderer());
    jSpinnerEnters.setValue(150);
    this.parent = parent;


    }



    public RendererContainer getListParameterModel(){
    return rc;
    }
    public int getNbrCenter(){
    return (Integer)jSpinnerEnters.getValue();
    }

    public int getNbrParameters(){
    return (Integer)jSpinnerParameter.getValue();
    }

    public int getPercentage(){
    return (Integer)jSpinnerPercent.getValue();
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jListParameter = new javax.swing.JList();
        jSpinnerEnters = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        jSpinnerParameter = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        jSpinnerPercent = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButtonColorChange = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(232, 213));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(232, 213));

        jListParameter.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        jListParameter.setToolTipText("");
        jListParameter.addListSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                jListParameterValueChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jListParameter);

        jSpinnerParameter.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 200, 1));
        jSpinnerParameter.setToolTipText("Range 1 to 200");
        jSpinnerParameter.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                jSpinnerParameterStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jSpinnerPercent.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                jSpinnerPercentStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Percent :");

        jLabel2.setText("El number :");

        jLabel3.setText("id number :");

        jButtonColorChange.setText("Change Color");
        jButtonColorChange.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonColorChangeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setText("Type | %");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, 0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGap(10, 10, 10))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButtonColorChange)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jSpinnerParameter, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jSpinnerEnters, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 45, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jSpinnerPercent, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(35, 35, 35))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jSpinnerCenters, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jSpinnerParameter, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jSpinnerPercent, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                        .addComponent(jButtonColorChange))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jSpinnerParameter.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleParent(jSpinnerParameter);

        getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleParent(this);
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jSpinnerPercentStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int selected = 0;

    if(jListParameter.getSelectedIndex() != -1){
        selected = jListParameter.getSelectedIndex();

    Parameter parameter = (Parameter) rc.getParameter(selected);
    if(jSpinnerPercent.getValue() instanceof Integer){
        Integer p = (Integer)jSpinnerPercent.getValue();
        double percent = DMath.round(p.doubleValue(), 2);
        parametersTable.setPercent(parameter, percent );
        rc.get(selected).add("%", percent);
    }else{
        double percent = DMath.round((Double)jSpinnerPercent.getValue(), 2);
        parametersTable.setPercent(parameter, percent );
        rc.get(selected).add("%", percent);

    }
    }
    jListParameter.repaint();

    }                                            

    private void jListParameterValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int selected = 0;

    if(jListParameter.getSelectedIndex() != -5)
        selected = jListParameter.getSelectedIndex();
    Parameter parameter = (Parameter) rc.getParameter(selected);
    jSpinnerPercent.setValue(parametersTable.getPercent(parameter));
    }                                           

    private void jSpinnerParameterStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    nbrParameter = (Integer)jSpinnerParameter.getValue();
    java.awt.Color tab[] = ImageTools.getColorsRGB(nbrParameter);

    rc.reset();
    parametersTable.reset();
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        Parameter param = new Parameter("TYPE", i, tab[i]);
        param.setName("TYPE");

        parametersTable.addParameter(param);
        double percent = DMath.round((double)100 / tab.length, 2);
        parametersTable.addToPercent(param, percent );
        ObjectRenderer or = new ObjectRenderer();
        or.addParameter(param);
        or.add("%", percent);
        rc.add(or);

    }

    this.validate();
    }                                              

    private void jButtonColorChangeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(!jListParameter.isSelectionEmpty()){

         JDialogColor jDialogColor = new JDialogColor(true,rc, jListParameter.getSelectedIndex(), JDialogColor.COLORCHANGE);
        jDialogColor.run();

    }

    }                                                  




@Override
    public Layer createLayer(String name) {

    nbrCenter = (Integer)jSpinnerEnters.getValue();
    SimpleLayer layer = null;
    Layer set = null;


        layer = new SimpleLayer(name);
        layer.setNbrCenter(nbrCenter);  
    //}
    layer.setGeometryType(Polygone.GEOMETRYTYPE);
    layer.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    layer.setParametersTable(parametersTable);
    layer.setType("TYPE");
    layer.setId("ID");
    parametersTable.setId("ID");
    layer.setupGraph(LayerFactory.getVor(parametersTable, nbrCenter, name));


    return layer;
    }

public void setValues(Layer layer){
    jSpinnerEnters.setValue(layer.getNbrCenter());
    jSpinnerParameter.setValue(layer.getParametersTable().getTypes().size());


    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)jListParameter.getModel();
    for(Parameter p : layer.types()){
        model.addElement(p);
    }
}





public int getAlerte() {

     int x = 0;
        if (Integer.parseInt(jSpinnerParameter.getValue().toString()) <= 0 ||
            Integer.parseInt(jSpinnerParameter.getValue().toString()) >200) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Color number must be minimum 1",
                    "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           x = 1; 
        }
        return x;  
}


    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonColorChange;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JList jListParameter;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinnerEnters;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinnerParameter;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinnerPercent;
    // End of variables declaration

    @Override
    public void refresh() {
    }

}
```

the problem is:
when i enter -1 or if click "ok" without entering any thing in the jSpinner it never displays the error message.

Comment: i tried to place my getAlert() in the beginning of the code and sitll it didn't work. thx